# Is a 40-50% Brokerage Fee Reasonable for Items Shipped Across the Border?

Tags: brokerage, shipping, customs

Recently I had a package shipped by UPS. When the man came he said I owed $49 in brokerage fees, almost HALF of the total value of the $100 item.

Is it reasonable to charge this much?

Comment: This is why I don't use UPS for x-border. Even Fedex is more reasonable, and much better service.

Comment: UPS charges fees for posting a bond on your package's import taxes if you don't give them a credit card to charge taxes to _prior_ to the package getting to customs. If you have to use UPS, doing this can lower the charge significantly.

Answer (score 2):

No, if it's UPS, just call them and complain about the high rate.

I did this and the cut it by half with only a bit of finageling. Remember, you can always go to your local customs office instead, but since this can take a whole afternoon it is reasonable to pay some sort of clearing fee.

Answer (score 0):

It's more like a flat fee, not a percentage. That is, they may charge you $49 to ship a $10 item (of the same bulk, under the same circumstances). And they may charge you the same $49 to ship a $10,000 item.

Now, $49 may be unreasonable, as another poster suggested. But if some lower number X is reasonable, it will likely apply to similar packages valued at $10, $100, or $10,000. After all, they did the same amount of worik.

Answer (score 0):

I once paid about $100 to clear $1400 of merchandise.  Part of that number is set by the broker, and part of it is set by the [Harmonized Tariff Schedule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonized_Tariff_Schedule_for_the_United_States).  The latter part is not adjustable and would be the same no matter which broker you go to.